# The instance of entity type 'Bot' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

> The instance of entity type 'Bot' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider us...

I know what this problem means. It is happening right here `_context.Bots.Update(bot);`.

The question is: is that a good way to solve this by adding `.AsNoTracking()` to all GetByXXX methods? Any suggestions?

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] BotCreateUpdateDto botCreateUpdateDto)
{
    if (id != botCreateUpdateDto.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = "Invalid ID." });
    }

    var user = await _userService.GetByEmailAsync(botCreateUpdateDto.Email);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = "Invalid e-mail." });
    }

    var cryptoPair = await _cryptoPairService.GetBySymbolAsync(botCreateUpdateDto.Symbol);

    if (cryptoPair == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = "Invalid crypto pair." });
    }

    var timeInterval = await _timeIntervalService.GetByIntervalAsync(botCreateUpdateDto.Interval);

    if (timeInterval == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = "Invalid time interval." });
    }

    var bot = new Bot
    {
        Id = botCreateUpdateDto.Id,
        Name = botCreateUpdateDto.Name,
        Status = botCreateUpdateDto.Status,
        UserId = user.Id,
        CryptoPairId = cryptoPair.Id,
        TimeIntervalId = timeInterval.Id
    };

    bool updated;

    try
    {
        updated = await _botService.UpdateAsync(bot);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = ex.Message });
    }

    if (updated)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

```
public async Task<User> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
{
    return await _context.Users
        .Include(e => e.UserRoles)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Role)
        .Include(e => e.Bots)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Email == email);
}
```

```
public async Task<CryptoPair> GetBySymbolAsync(string symbol)
{
    return await _context.CryptoPairs
        .Include(e => e.Bots)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Symbol == symbol);
}
```

```
public async Task<TimeInterval> GetByIntervalAsync(KlineInterval interval)
{
    return await _context.TimeIntervals
        .Include(e => e.Bots)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Interval == interval);
}
```

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Bot bot)
{
    _context.Bots.Update(bot);
    var updated = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return updated > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I really didn't realise that I was creating a new Bot object instead of just getting it by id. There is also no point of `.AsNoTracking`.

```
var bot = await _botService.GetByIdAsync(id);
bot.Name = botCreateUpdateDto.Name;
bot.Status = botCreateUpdateDto.Status;
bot.CryptoPairId = cryptoPair.Id;
bot.TimeIntervalId = timeInterval.Id;
```

This solves the problem for anyone having same problem as me. Keep in mind that my all services are scoped as well as the DbContext. If yours are singleton, that will cause this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue like :
The instance of entity type 'ClassName' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}'
is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance
with a given key value is attached.

I resolved with remove this .AsNoTracking() when fetch data from DB.