# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm getting a same key value runtime exception from entity base class. I tried few online solutions with no lucks. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Following line throwing Exception when I try to update:

this.RepositoryContext.Set().Update(entity);

Framework : .netcore 3.1

Error:

{"The instance of entity type 'JobConnection' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'JobConnectionId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."}.

Here is the call:

```
public void UpdateJobConn(JobConnection jobfile)
        {
            Update(jobfile);
            Save();
        }
```

Here is the whole Repository class:

```
using Foreside.Etp.Contracts;
using Foreside.Etp.Entities.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foreside.Etp.Repository
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        protected EtpRepoContext RepositoryContext { get; set; }

        public RepositoryBase(EtpRepoContext repositoryContext)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);
        }

        public void Create(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

JobConnection Model -

```
public partial class JobConnection
    {
        public int JobConnectionId { get; set; }
        public int KeyId { get; set; }
        public int ConnectionId { get; set; }
        public string Directory { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int ConnectiontypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

Context -

```
 public virtual DbSet<JobConnection> JobConnection { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<JobConnection>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("job_connection");

            entity.HasKey(e => e.JobConnectionId);

            entity.Property(e => e.JobConnectionId)
                .HasColumnName("jobconnectionid")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.ConnectionId)
                .HasColumnName("connectionid")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("0");

            entity.Property(e => e.ConnectiontypeId)
                .HasColumnName("connectiontypeid")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Directory)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("directory")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("0");

            entity.Property(e => e.JobId)
                .HasColumnName("jobid")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.KeyId)
                .HasColumnName("keyid")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("0");
        });
```

Table  -

```
SHOW INDEXES
FROM job_connection

job_connection  0   PRIMARY 1   jobconnectionid A   63              BTREE
```

Comment: Message is self explanatory. You're creating a duplicate key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance of entity type 'Bot' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521320/the-instance-of-entity-type-bot-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-wit)

Comment: I understand it's similar, but I'm not exactly able to fit that solution here. I'm new to .netcore. Can you please modify the code above if you can? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @T.S - I understand I'm somehow creating a duplicate key. But in code how can I fix it? I'm not able to figure out how to stop it - I'm not creating any new instance. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: may be before you do `update`, you set new `JobConnectionId` on your model, id which is already used by another record

Comment: It's pretty difficult to find that new JobConnectionId in Code. Is there any way to find out in code at the time of update?

Comment: *"I understand it's similar, but ...* - it will never be the same because every one has a different model they pass. Causation, however is the same.  *"But in code how can I fix it?*" - you catch this error and return an error code, something like "supplied data is duplicating existing data". Unless you want to remove constraint and get duplicate data. *"may be before you do update..."* even if you go and try to retrieve original record with same ID you still need to send error code that you can't accept this data. In fact, your code works correctly. Its the data bad

Comment: Okay. But when I check data model I see JobConnectionId is the primary key and we are trying to update a record that has no delicate in database table. We are not inserting anything in table to duplicate it rather updating an existing record that is not duplicate in Table. So there is no way "supplied data is duplicating existing data". Would you be able to share your thoughts on it? Sometimes discussing helps to solve the issue.

Comment: There could be a unique key on another column, There could be a model marked as unique column. There could be something in the context.

Comment: "There could be a unique key on another column" -- I don't find any unique key except jobconnectionid column which is the primary key of the table. That's the only index is set to that table. "There could be a model marked as unique column or context" -- There is no unique key marked in model or context. I've added model and context code above for our reference. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried setting your entity to modified?  entity.State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Yes - tried this code with luck. RepositoryContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue by detaching the EntityState. I really appreciate for sharing your thoughts - it helped to think it through. Please find the problem and the correct solution below.

Problem :

There was at least an orphan tracked instance preventing from working with the correct instance that I want to update in DB - basically this is a duplicate instance which was interfering when context was trying to update in DB and were not able to save any references for JobConnection. Context was somehow storing references on inserted objects even after leaving scope of their declaration and initialization.

Solution:

There could be multiple ways to solve this issue. One of the ways is to detach the instance from context in order to avoid similar orphaned duplicate instances which was causing issues for our case. Here is an example how I fixed in code :

```
_context.Entry<JobConnection>(jobCon).State = EntityState.Detached;  //Explicitly Detach the orphan tracked instance
```

Another example in code that has similar issue and here is the solution.

```
var inFiles = _filerepository.FindAllInboundFilesByJobId(job.Jobid);
foreach (File inFile in inFiles)
_context.Entry<File>(inFile).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not using something like `entity.HasKey(a => a.Id);` to indicate primary key. hence the DB row id is clashing with the object you have in memory that you are trying to update.

You should debug and check the id of the object you are updating right before `this.RepositoryContext.SaveChanges();` is called.

Comment: Thank you, Guven. Good catch. But adding HasKey doesn't fix the issue. I've added the context section with modified code that I tried. Can you please check if I did any mistake? Thanks